# Difference between two consecutive mongodb documents fields

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a time-series collection in mongodb. Which looks like this:

```
{ _id: 1, time: 2021-01-03T06:26:20.000+00:00 }
{ _id: 2, time: 2021-01-03T06:26:21.000+00:00 }
{ _id: 3, time: 2021-01-03T06:26:22.000+00:00 }
```

I want to accumulate all document based on time field and all documents are sorted based on time field. And output should be look like (t3-t2) + (t2-t1). So for this output will be 2 seconds.

For postgresql we can use window function or joins to calculated. How to calculate this in mongodb?

Comment: Why not `t3 - t1`? Should be the same.

Comment: Mathematically `t3-t1` is correct. But at some point I want to skip some rows. For this example, let say I want to skip `_id: 3`. So in that case answer will be `t2-t1`

Answer (score 0):

You an use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: { $ne: 3 } } },
   { $group: { _id: null, max_time: { $max: "$time" }, min_time: { $min: "$time" } } },
   { $set: { difference: { $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$max_time", "$min_time"] }, 1000] } } }
])
```